# Integration with respect to signed measure and Radon Nikodym theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I aim to show the following question:

> Let $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure, and $\lambda$ a finite signed measure on $(X,M)$ satisfying $\lambda\ll\mu$, let $h=\frac{d\lambda}{d\mu}\in L^1(\mu)$. Show that $$\int fd\lambda=\int fhd\mu,\quad\forall f\in L^1(\lambda),fh\in L^1(\mu)$$

**Approach in Suggested Solution**

$\underline{Step1}$, let $f=\chi_E, E\in M$ then $$\int \chi_E d\lambda=\lambda(E)=\int_E h d\mu=\int \chi_E h d\mu$$

Then let $s\ge 0$, $s$ be simple function, the statement also follows.

$\underline{Step2}$ let $f\ge 0$, measurable, pick $0\le s\le f$, then $0\le sh\leq fh$ on $\{h\ge 0\}$, and $0\le -sh\leq -fh$ on $\{h< 0\}$, hence

$$\begin{align}\int  f d\lambda&=\int_{\{h\ge 0\}}f d\lambda-\int_{\{h< 0\}}-f d\lambda\\
&=\sup_{0\le s\le f}\int_{\{h\ge 0\}}s d\lambda-\color{blue}{\sup_{0\le s\le f}\int_{\{h< 0\}}-s d\lambda}=\cdots
\end{align}$$

**My approach**

I use the definition that $\color{green}{\int fd\lambda=\int fd\lambda^+-\int fd\lambda^-}$, where $\lambda^+,\lambda^-$ is the Jordan decomposition of $\lambda$.

Step 1 is the similar to above except the definition. $\int \chi_E d\lambda=\int \chi_E d\lambda^+-\int \chi_E d\lambda^-=\lambda^+(E)-\lambda^-(E)=\lambda(E)=\cdots$

$\underline{Step2}$ I use monotone convergence theorem.

Let $f\ge 0$, measurable, pick $0\le s_n\uparrow f$, then $0\le s_nh\uparrow fh$ on $\{h\ge 0\}$, and $0\le -s_nh\uparrow -fh$ on $\{h< 0\}$, by step 1( for the last identity),
$$\int_{\{h< 0\}} s_n d\lambda^+-\int_{\{h< 0\}} s_n d\lambda^-=\int_{\{h< 0\}} s_n d\lambda=-\int_{\{h< 0\}} -s_nhd\mu$$
Then by MCT, LHS and RHS converges to corresponding limits hence
$$\int_{\{h< 0\}} f d\lambda^+-\int_{\{h< 0\}} f d\lambda^-=-\int_{\{h< 0\}} -fhd\mu=-\int fh^-d\mu$$
The last identity uses the definition of $h^-$, similarly, we have
$$\int_{\{h\ge 0\}} f d\lambda^+-\int_{\{h\ge 0\}} f d\lambda^-=\int fh^+d\mu$$

Add above two equation, we have $$\int f d\lambda^+-\int f d\lambda^-=\int fhd\mu$$
Then by definition of integration w.r.t signed measure, we have $\int fd\lambda=\int fhd\mu$

**Questions**

1. It seems that my definition ($\color{green}{green}$ color text)  is different from  that used in the suggested solution. It seems to define integration with signed measure analogue to integration with measure, that is from simple function to nonnegative measurable function to integrable function. **Which definition is correct? Is there any standard definition?**
2. Why the $\color{blue}{blue}$ colored step in the suggested solution is correct? In the case $-f<0$ is the definition of integral still be $\sup$?
3. Is my approach correct? I will discuss the case $f$ is integrable in my step 3. But I think that part is easier.

I am sorry it's a long post. But since I am not confident enough to judge which step is correct, I included all the related steps in my post. Please let me know if there is anything unclear. Also I know it's usually not a good idea to ask three questions in one post, but I think they are highly related here, so I decided to include all of them. Thanks!